# Print php time in datetime format starting from last 5 minutes with range of every minute

Tags: php, datetime

I need to print the start and end time of where the difference of start and end time in 1 minute. The fetching will start from the last 7th minutes until the last 2 minutes. That means the time from last five minutes. Here is the code I have written

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format(microtime(true), 6, '.', ''));
$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));

for($count = 5 ; $count >0 ; $count--){
$time_to_check = 0-($count+1);
$now =  $time->modify($count.' minutes');
$now_check =  $time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
$last_checked_time =  $time->modify('-59 seconds');
$last_checked = $last_checked_time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");

echo "start: ".$now_check."<br>";
echo "end: ".$last_checked."<br><br>";
}
```

for example, if the current time is `2021-03-03 22:26.416352`

Expected output will be:

```
start: 2021-03-03 22:20:30.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:21:29.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:21:30.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:22:29.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:22:30.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:23:29.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:23:30.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:24:29.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:24:30.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:25:29.416352
```

But i am getting the following output:

```
start: 2021-03-03 22:29:30.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:28:31.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:32:31.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:31:32.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:34:32.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:33:33.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:35:33.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:34:34.416352

start: 2021-03-03 22:35:34.416352
end: 2021-03-03 22:34:35.416352
```

I am getting future time in my output and the difference is not 1 minute one from another. How can I do this efficiently? Thanks

Comment: Please add some example data, expected output and what you currently (with the posted code) are getting.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do or where it goes wrong. I'd suggest reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get some tips on writing a good question.

Comment: I have edited the output and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you're asking for but I'll try to help.

I believe you're asking for how to print from increments of 1 minute from T - 7 minutes to T - 2 minutes? You can achieve this with a simple for loop where you instantiate the time to 7 minutes and then just increment the time by one minute over each iteration of the loop. Here's a sample snippet:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("-7 minutes");

for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    print_r("start: " . $date->format("m/d/Y H:i:s"));
    $date->modify("+1 minutes");
    print_r("end: " . $date->format("m/d/Y H:i:s"));
}
```

You're continually modifying the same DateTime object. Just initialize it once and then perform the rudimentary calculation.